# Someone is saying that they haven’t received their money but I show that deposit is in the blockchain. What is going on?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I’ve sent someone Bitcoin via Cashapp. I’ve received notice that the withdrawal have been posted to the blockchain but the person says they haven’t received nor can they see it. Can someone explain this. I did send it “regular speed” so it should show up within 24 hours but they are impatient. Should I believe them or do you think they are not telling me the truth.

Comment: can you please post the transaction ID? That way we can confirm that this has in fact been confirmed and the counter-party is lying. Otherwise it is possible that they have not received it yet, if the transaction is stuck in the mempool or something.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say “in the blockchain” and “posted to the blockchain”, do you mean that it was included in a block (i.e. confirmed) or that it was submitted to the Bitcoin network?